# Why isn't my server restarting / code updating using Docker + Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docker

My docker file is super simple:

```
FROM node:4-onbuild
RUN npm install gulp -g;
EXPOSE 8888
```

This image will automatically run the `start` script in `package.json` which I have set simply as `gulp`.

If I run `gulp` on my host machine, and make a change to node file, it automatically restarts server:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js', // starts up server on port 4000
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })
});
```

Figuring everything is okay I run this: `docker run -d -p 1234:4000 -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app my-image`

Going to `http://192.168.99.100:1234/` shows 'Hello World!' from my `server.js` file. Updating the file does NOT update what I see by hitting that URL again. If I exec into the container, I see the file is updated. Since the container started node via the same gulp command, I don't understand why the node server wouldn't have restarted and shown the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TL;DR of this is that you need to set nodemon to poll the filesystem for changes as follows: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

> In some networked environments (such as a container running nodemon reading across a mounted drive), you will need to use the legacyWatch: true which enabled Chokidar's polling.
>
> Via the CLI, use either --legacy-watch or -L

The longer version is this (with one key assumption - you're using docker on Mac or similar):

On Mac or similar, docker doesn't run natively and instead runs inside of a virtual machine (generally virtual box via docker-machine). Virtual machines generally don't propagate filesystem inotify events, which is what most watchers rely on to restart or perform an action when a file changes. As the virtual machine doesn't propagate the events from the host, Docker never receives the events. Your original docker file would *probably* work on a native linux machine.

There's an open issue and much more detailed discussion of this [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18246).